# How to ensure that the Pancakes get cooked evenly?

Tags: pancakes

The last time I made pancakes, while they were nicely cooked on the outside, they were still a bit "battery" in the middle.  Does anyone has a simple solution to try?

Comment: Is this actually referring to American hotcakes or flapjacks? Pancakes should not be that thick to have a middle to not cook? A pancake is a non-transparent crepe, but still very thin

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might try reducing the cooking heat a little, say on medium heat.  That way, the middle will finish cooking without the outside being overcooked.  And usually when you flip a pancake it should be almost entirely cooked through anyway.  You want to flip when the bubbles are pretty set on the top.

Comment: Yep, that's the ticket.

Comment: I have always read (and always followed) that the pan should be hot enough that a droplet of water will 'dance' across it. My golden rule is to add your batter, then count the number of bubbles that pop; once ten bubbles pop, flip your pancake.

Comment: Wow, what a difference!

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the heat a little. Make the mix thinner so you can use less of it and still have it spread to fill the pan: a thinner pancake will cook all the way through quicker.

Comment: To have a thinner batter that still produces a fluffy pancake, use ample amounts of baking powder.

Comment: +1 for thinner mix. Generally, if it's not cooked in the middle, your batter is too thick.